# Automatic build with clearcase

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-automation

Is there any way to build for multiple targets using the ClearCase Automation Layer or maybe by creating a perl script? I would like to automate the process of building for both Linux and windows when a project is checked in. Any inputs would be appreciated.

Regards,
Magnus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the continuous integration server [Jenkins](http://www.jenkins-ci.org)' matrix configurations to build for multiple targets and use either the [Base ClearCase Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+Plugin) or the ClearCase UCM Plugin, depending on your ClearCase installation.

Currently, though, the ClearCase UCM Plugin does not have Linux support, but it is on the way.

Sorry, couldn't add all the links I wanted, because of too little rep.

Comment: The base clearcase plugin is supposed to have UCM support, but it is not documented.

Comment: Thanks alot! I'll look in to Jenkins and the clearCase Plugin. I'm completely new to this, so anything more you could tell me would be really usefull. Thanks again!

Comment: You should start with [link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Use+Jenkins), which covers the basics of Jenkins. The matrix configuration(or the multi-configuration project) can define multiple axes of information for you to use in the build.

Comment: Actually, just download Jenkins, it's Java and completely self contained, so it's fairly easy start and rather intuitive. Under Manage Jenkins -> Manage plugins -> Available, you can find the ClearCase Plugin and the ClearCase UCM Plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The **[configuration matrix](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+matrix+project)** is made for "instances where your builds will make many similar build steps, and you would otherwise be duplicating steps."

The step that will differ is the ClearCase view creation/parametrization, different for each platform, since the ClearCase region, view storage path and file separators will be different.
Even if you are using UCM, the base ClearCase plugin is enough to detect changes on the branch: use the name of the Stream as the branch.